# Getting an error when try to run docker file (ERROR: Service failed to build)

Tags: docker, dockerfile

My project has the following structure:

`docker-compose.yml` - docker-compose file I created

`schemathesis` - a folder with source code and dockerfile

Where `docker-compose.yml` is:

```
version: '3'
services:
  schemathesis:
    build: ./schemathesis
    ports:
      - "8180:80"    
    networks:
      - default
```

Dockerfile in schemathesis folder looks like:

```
FROM python:3.10-alpine

LABEL Name=Schemathesis

WORKDIR /app

RUN addgroup --gid 1000 -S schemathesis && \
    adduser --uid 1000 -D -S schemathesis -G schemathesis -s /sbin/nologin

COPY --chown=1000:1000 pyproject.toml README.rst src ./

RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual=.build-deps build-base libffi-dev curl openssl-dev && \
    curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh -s -- -y && \
    source $HOME/.cargo/env && \
    pip install --upgrade pip && pip install --no-cache-dir ./ && \
    apk del .build-deps && \
    rustup self uninstall -y

# Needed for the `.hypothesis` directory
RUN chown -R 1000:1000 /app

USER schemathesis
ENTRYPOINT ["schemathesis"]
```

When I run: `sudo docker-compose up --build` I am getting an error ERROR: `Service 'schemathesis' failed to build`:

```
Building schemathesis
Step 1/9 : FROM python:3.10-alpine
 ---> 8a3a8409a638
Step 2/9 : LABEL Name=Schemathesis
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f108325765ba
Step 3/9 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9fc24fc24456
Step 4/9 : RUN addgroup --gid 1000 -S schemathesis &&     adduser --uid 1000 -D -S schemathesis -G schemathesis -s /sbin/nologin
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 64881e35ad07
Step 5/9 : COPY --chown=1000:1000 pyproject.toml README.rst src ./
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8b9dfeb0ed09
Step 6/9 : RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual=.build-deps build-base libffi-dev curl openssl-dev &&     curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh -s -- -y &&     source $HOME/.cargo/env &&     pip install --upgrade pip && pip install --no-cache-dir ./ &&     apk del .build-deps &&     rustup self uninstall -y
 ---> Running in fafc492c1f99
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.17/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.17/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
WARNING: Ignoring https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.17/main: temporary error (try again later)
WARNING: Ignoring https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.17/community: temporary error (try again later)
ERROR: unable to select packages:
  .build-deps-20230120.185651:
    masked in: cache
    satisfies: world[.build-deps=20230120.185651]
  build-base (no such package):
    required by: .build-deps-20230120.185651[build-base]
  libffi-dev (no such package):
    required by: .build-deps-20230120.185651[libffi-dev]
  curl (no such package):
    required by: .build-deps-20230120.185651[curl]
  openssl-dev (no such package):
    required by: .build-deps-20230120.185651[openssl-dev]
ERROR: Service 'schemathesis' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apk add --no-cache --virtual=.build-deps build-base libffi-dev curl openssl-dev &&     curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh -s -- -y &&     source $HOME/.cargo/env &&     pip install --upgrade pip && pip install --no-cache-dir ./ &&     apk del .build-deps &&     rustup self uninstall -y' returned a non-zero code: 5
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code. It looks like you were unable to connect to dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org. Did you get a chance to try it again later?

Answer (score 0):

No idea what was the problem but the following set of command solve it:

```
sudo service firewalld stop
sudo service docker restart
sudo systemctl daemon-reload; systemctl restart docker
```